# TRUE/FALSE indicator in data table

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a list

```
list = c('td', 't', 'uo')
```

and I would like to test that each element of a column of my dataframe is in the list

```
list_in =  data[, .(column_A)] %in% list
```

However I receive only a unique TRUE/FALSE indicator. I would like a TRUE/FALSE indicator by row
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do:

```
list = c('td', 't', 'uo')

# sample data frame 
df = data.table(a = c('td','bo','uo'))

df[, flag := a %in% list]

    a  flag
1: td  TRUE
2: bo FALSE
3: uo  TRUE
```

Comment: many thanks it works better. i added return(df$flag) at the end of my function